# sklearn train_test_split: where to add average=None when we get: "Target is multiclass but average='binary'... error?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I know that I should add `average=None` somewhere but I dont really know, the target variables is a set of numbers:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

trainset, testset = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

def preprocessing(df):
    
    
    X = df.drop('log_price', axis=1)
    y = df['log_price'] 
    
    print(y.value_counts())
    
    return X, y

X_train, y_train = preprocessing(trainset)

X_test, y_test = preprocessing(testset)



from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve

def evaluation(model):
    
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    ypred = model.predict(X_test)
    
    print(confusion_matrix(y_test, ypred))
    print(classification_report(y_test, ypred))
    
    N, train_score, val_score = learning_curve(model, X_train, y_train,
                                              cv=4, scoring='f1',
                                                train_sizes=np.linspace(0.1, 1, 10))
    
    
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
    plt.plot(N, train_score.mean(axis=1), label='train score')
    plt.plot(N, val_score.mean(axis=1), label='validation score')
    plt.legend()



from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC 
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, f_classif
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures, StandardScaler

preprocessor = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(2, include_bias=False), SelectKBest(f_classif, k=10))

KNN = make_pipeline(preprocessor, StandardScaler(), KNeighborsClassifier())

dict_of_models = {
                  'KNN': KNN
                 }


for name, model in dict_of_models.items():
    print(name)
    evaluation(model)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError: Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose another average setting, one of [None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted'].
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the error traceback. First guess: you need to provide the `scoring` parameter of `learning_curve` as the full scorer instead of the string `f1` if you want to set its options.

Comment: Traceback: https://pastebin.com/yhPRtmAH

I can't add it to my original post because it's too long. Note that his code works perfectly with a binary target.
If I remove the learning_curve I don't get an error...

Comment: Looking at the confusion matrix in your link... Is there a particular reason you're using classification here instead of regression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error appears because you are using `'f1'` for the scoring parameter in `learning_curve`. This is only meant to be used with *binary targets*. However, as the error message indicates, your underlying problem is a **multiclass** problem. Hence, you need another scoring method with an appropriate averaging strategy. Predefined values can be found [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter). An example using `'f1_macro'`:

```
N, train_score, val_score = learning_curve(model, X_train, y_train,
                                           cv=4, 
                                           scoring='f1_macro', # <-- change here
                                           train_sizes=np.linspace(0.1, 1, 10)
)
```

As a reference how the `macro` averaging works:

> Calculate metrics for each label and find their unweighted mean. This does not take label imbalance into account.

More options can be found via the provided link. I am not aware of an equivalent to `None` that returns scores for each class.